# Java XSLT transform very slow when run on server during performance tests

Tags: java, performance, xslt

I have template.newTransformer().transform(src,res). src is a JAXBsource of a POJO and res is SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

On local setup running 1 query at a time, its fine 1.3-2.5 seconds. But on server when running performance tests waiting time raises to up to 49 seconds per request.

Template itself is rather simple but large. It is a localized templare

3 languages are on the document at a time.

```
<xsl:variable name="primary" select="document(concat('classpath:/pdf/translation.', $primarylang,'.xml'))"/>
<xsl:variable name="secondary" select="document(concat('classpath:/pdf/translation.', $secondaryLang,'.xml'))"/>
<xsl:variable name="terniary" select="document(concat('classpath:/pdf/translation.', $terniaryLang,'.xml'))"/>
```

And then document consist of alot of

```
<xsl:call-template name="getTranslation">
<xsl:with-param name="key" select="'key'"/>
<xsl:with-param name="lang" select="$lang"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

And the template itself is

```
<xsl:template name="getTranslation">
<xsl:param name="lang"/>
<xsl:param name="key"/>
<xsl:value-of= select="$lang/language/data[@name=$key]/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Rest of the template is standard xsl:fo setup for PDF.

Comment: Is it the exact same JDK (and version) on the server ?

Comment: Yep sam java version

Comment: So where is the first parameter `lang` declared/bound? Is that XSLT 1 or 2/3? Have you considered declaring a key `<xsl:key name="data" match="language/data" use="@name"/>` and then in XSLT 2 or 3 using e.g. `key('data', $key, $lang)` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$lang/language/data[@name=$key]/text()"/>` or in XSLT 1 `<xsl:for-each select="$lang"><xsl:value-of select="key('data', $key)"/></xsl:for-each>`? Using keys speeds up the cross-reference lookup I would think.

Comment: lang is either $primaryLang, $secndaryLang, $terniaryLang and they are given from java side. But the keys and XSLT 2.0 gona try

Comment: For a chronic performance problem like this, check whether the transformation is generating any HTTP traffic. A common cause is fetching resources (such as a well known DTD or XSD) from the W3C server, which deliberately throttles access to prevent server overload.

Comment: Well im not alteas including any. i only have XSL, FO and FOX. might be able to remove FOX. But if DTD or XSD is to blame, how to get around it?

Comment: Usually a catalog resolver helps to work with local copies if you have e.g. XHTML referencing the official W3C XHTML DTD.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Your key approach... i dont know if i cna use it. As i have 3 files with same sturcture, only difference is the values themselves. Key seems to work only wiht 1 fiel, i cant see a way to specify the file/variable from whitch to take the value. Maybe example not clear enough. Basically.. the getTranslation template uses XPath to find translation to key from $lang where lang can be either primary, secondary or terniary. I dont think key can work in this case since primary, secondary and terniary are variables.

Comment: Keys are built per document, that is correct, but of course you can use them with different documents, as I did already show in my comment, in XSLT 2 and 3 the `key` function takes a third argument for the document or in general subtree to search `key('data', $key, $lang)` and in XSLT 1 you need to switch the context document as I also did show with `xsl:for-each`: `<xsl:for-each select="$lang"><xsl:value-of select="key('data', $key)"/></xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Updated to XSLT 2. Using KEY to get the value. Also pre-cashin the translation files with java and passing them in as parameters. substituteed the call-temlpates with key. Still next to no improvement... I suspect it might be the table elements in the xsl.Althoug even empty template takes 2.5 seconds... With graphana we can see at somepoint CPU reaches 100% and request start to fail.

Comment: I am sorry that my suggestions on using keys in XSLT did not help. On the other hand, the fact that your local setup gives you an acceptable performance but the server not indicates that it might not be an XSLT problem. Perhaps others have some more and better ideas.

Comment: I added in Executor thread pool. And now experimenting on concurrent connections. I have found that atleast on my laptop somewhere 150-175 executros is the sweetspot of performance. Need to do the same on the server too i guess. that one is alot weaker but need some testing to see where the sweetspot might lie. Out of the 2-3 secconds i know where 1 second comes from. rest is XSLT and FOP.